# My images won't load

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to make a gallery with several image tags like so:[image: my image tags] 
My img folder looks like this: [image: my folder structure]Although probably a simple fix, I just can't seem to make the connection. The console states:[image: console] Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: http://www.genuinescope.com/blog/tag/the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-403-forbidden/

Comment: It just means that the server cannot find your image.

Comment: You might not have sufficient permission to read the images. If you are on linux, navigate to the `img` directory in a terminal, and try `chmod 777 -v *`. Please note, though, that it is unsafe to set `777` permissions to resources on a production environment.

Comment: @AvinashBabu: If I am not wrong, the server should have returned a `404` if it was unable to find the resource. But it has returned a `403` which usually means a permission issue, or a `.htaccess` gone bad.

Comment: Please also *read* what the console says. It says *"forbidden"*. Which means you or your service account does not have proper permissions as CEP said.

Comment: @CEP you are right ..:)

Comment: I'm using apache thatJavaNerd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a [403 (Forbidden) HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), which - as its name implies - means that the server has denied access to you.

Make sure that, in the `img` folder there is no .htaccess file that is denying access (`deny from` among its contents).

Note the difference between this case, and the [404 (Not found)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) for the stylesheet.